# Newbie string error

Tags: android, eclipse, string

Can you tell me why there is an error on each string line?

```
<string> name="app_name">Bootle JFL</string>
<string> name="hello_world">Hello world</string>
<string> name="action_settings">Settings</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
 <string name="app_name">Bootle JFL</string>
 <string name="hello_world">Hello world</string>
 <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
```

`name` is the attribute for the tag string and attribute must be within the string tag.

Read

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 2):

you closed the string tag too earlier

```
 <string name="app_name"> Bootle JFL</string>
```

for all the strings,

Comment: This should be the right answer, as the op asks "why" the lines are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 closing > should be like

`<string name="app_name">Bootle JFL</string>`